# Is there an R function for pie chart on a ggplot map that work with this kind of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

For my master thesis I would need to do a map (possibly with ggplot) with pie charts on it, I've read many threads about the library scatterpie but it doesn't work with my data.
My data are something like this:

| Long | Lat | Abundance | Names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | 3 | Jhonny |
| X | Y | 1 | Manuel |
| X | Y | 2 | Mike |

Scatterpie function doesn't work because it asks that "the slices" of the pie are different columns of the data frame. Instead, I would need a pie in which the slices are each name of the Names column and the width of the slice that corresponds to the Abundance variable.

Is there a function that does this?

Comment: Could you not pivot your data into wide format to give `scatterpie` what it wants?

Comment: [Here's the FAQ for pivoting data from long to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/903061). Something like `tidyr::pivot_wider(your_data, names_from = Names, values_from = Abundance)` should do it.

Comment: yes, this function changed my data into wide format but I still have problems with geom_scatterpie(). I'm using this code:             ggplot() +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = long, y = lat), cols = c(22:25), data = my_data) +
  coord_fixed()            the plot background appears but is blank and the console gives me the warning "Removed 4532 rows containing non-finite values (stat_pie)."